# Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList"

Tags: powershell, scripting, runtime-error, public-folders

*Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.PublicFolderIdParameter".* is the entire error...

Basically, we want to migrate our pub folders to shared boxes and I am attempting to get public folder permissions on the existing structure...

The issue is with the last line here... I am not sure why it is throwing this. I originally wanted to bind the alias, rather than the display name, but apparently, the display name has spaces that are needed to identify them... In any case, this is where I am stuck...

```
$mepf     = Get-MailPublicFolder "Pub Folder Name" -ResultSize unlimited
$alias    = $mepf.displayname
$pf       = get-publicfolder -Recurse -ResultSize unlimited | ? {$_.Identity -match "$alias"}
$identity = $pf.Identity
$perms    = Get-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity $pf.Identity | Where-Object {$_.User -notmatch "Default|Anonymous"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty User
```

Comment: $pf is possibly an array (collection) of public folders and as such `$pf.Identity` will be an array of the identities of all of those public folders.  It appears that `Get-PublicFolderClientPermission`'s Identity parameter only wants a single identity and not a collection of identities.

Comment: `$mepf` is also a collection, so `$mepf.displayname` will become an array of displaynames.

Comment: @Daniel, so should I then use a foreach? I will tinker with this. Thanks

Comment: Ok I have added a foreach after the $PFs variable and it seems to be working... Naturally, I have a new issue though, but let's save that for another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it is working... Thanks, Daniel!

```
$mepf     = Get-MailPublicFolder "PubFolderName" -ResultSize unlimited
$alias    = $mepf.displayname
$pfs      = get-publicfolder -Recurse -ResultSize unlimited | ? {$_.Identity -match "$alias"}

foreach ($pf in $pfs){
$identity = $pf.Identity

$perms    = Get-PublicFolderClientPermission -Identity $pf.Identity | Where-Object {$_.User -notmatch "Default|Anonymous"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty User
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`$pf` will most likely contain more than one folder, so `$pf.Identity` will return an array of identities.

Try piping the input:

```
get-publicfolder -Recurse -ResultSize unlimited |
   where {$_.Identity -match "$alias"} |
   Get-PublicFolderClientPermission | foreach {
       # do something with $_
   }
```

Comment: ok, I will play around with this, thanks.

Comment: Yep... Out of memory... the array is massive... Back to the drawing board. I think it would have worked if there weren't so many objects...

Comment: @MarcEverlove The purpose of a pipeline (like this), is not saving all the results in a variable (`$perms = ...`) but then again pipe the results into the *next* command you want to run on the results. That's exactly what a pipeline is for and how you prevent any memory issues (see my edit).